# jquery two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and javascript as a whole. I tried doing two things, but only one of them is working. I have to change the color, as well as increase the counter as explained below. Need help with the code.
Examples -

```
1 click - 1
2 clicks - 11
5 clicks - 11111
```

Code - HTML

```
<div id="flash"> <p>hello</p>
    </div>
<div id="counter">0</div>​
```

Code - JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('p').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'color': 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'
    }, 500);
});
$("#flash").click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(function(i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 1;
    });
});
});​
```

Code - CSS

```
p { font-weight: bold; display: inline; cursor: pointer; }​
```

Here is my code that I tried to play with - http://jsfiddle.net/crlf/pVHYc/

Comment: You should avoid coming here with a link and a "go figure it out" statement. Present the question for us here, provide your broken code in the post and then provide a link to jsfiddle as needed. You haven't even stated what your problem is for us to help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include jQueryUI to animate colours with `.animate()`

For the counter you can concatenate `1`s to it, just check if it is `0` and replace with `1` or concatenate a `1`.

```
return val =='0'?1: val + 1;
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/pVHYc/6/

Comment: oh! great. thanks a tonne. the animation issue is solved. any help with displaying the output as '111' for 3 clicks instead of addition?

Comment: put String(val) at the return statment, imean dont add but concatenate

Comment: return string(val); --> this doesn't return anything on output.

Answer (score 0):

solved both animate and output problem.

animate is due to not including jquery UI

output is wrong because you are trying to add but try concatenation

http://jsfiddle.net/pVHYc/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('p').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'color': 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'
    }, 500);
});
$("#flash").click(function() {
    $('#counter').html(function(i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 1;
    });
});
});
```